# routes.rb Rails 2 vs. Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use the following Rails 3 route and convert it to Rails 2 syntax:

```
match '/party/:id', :to => "rooms#party", :as => :party, :via => :get
```

Comment: This route could also be written as `get '/party/:id', :to => "rooms#party", :as => :party`, FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
map.party "/party/:id", :controller => "rooms", :action => "party"
```

If you want to limit it to only get, then add `the following:

```
:conditions => { :method => :get }`
```

cheers